# AmCharts Gantt chart ZoomTIndexes not working

Tags: amcharts, gantt-chart

here is my code

```
listeners: [{
        event: "init",
        method: function (e) {
            e.chart.zoomToIndexes(0, 19);
        }
    }],
```

this is not working with Amcharts gantt chart

https://www.amcharts.com/demos/gantt-chart/

Comment: Usually this happens if the values are out of range. Would you mind to share the whole code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorted out the problem..

```
listeners: [{
        event: "init",
        method: function (e) {
            e.chart.valueAxis.zoomToValues(new Date(startZoomDate), new Date(endZoomDate));
        }
    }]
```

above code worked fine for me!

thanks